# Execute onClick function on Custom Legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, legend

I've added a function "Pie_onClickLegend_HighlightOnSlice(event, legendItem)" used in options > legend > onClick, and I'd like to use it also with my custom legend. But I don't know how to pass the legendItem outside of my chart.

[image: on top my custom legend, on buttom the original legend]

on top: my custom legend (with onClick not working)

on buttom: "original" legend (with onClick function working)

I think the problem is with the way I'm calling my function "Pie_onClickLegend_HighlightOnSlice"

```
document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = 

chartTurn.generateLegend().replace(/\"0-legend"/g, 'legend');
$("#js-legend > ul > li").on("click", function(e) {
  var index = $(this).index();

  Pie_onClickLegend_HighlightOnSlice(e.originalEvent, chartTurn.legend.legendItems[index]);
  ci.update();
```

Do you have some suggestion? I think the problem is in

```
chartTurn.legend.legendItems[index]
```

but I don't know what to use.

https://jsfiddle.net/stamina/x2pbnoes/89/

Comment: I suggest to check with my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/b5hdn9gw/

Comment: I edited my code using your suggestion. This is how it is now:
https://jsfiddle.net/stamina/x2pbnoes/114/

Comment: So it's working, there is only an error in console cause by `ci.update();` line 102

Comment: Yes, I forgot to remove the line. https://jsfiddle.net/stamina/x2pbnoes/118/

Answer (score 0):

With beaver's suggestion, I found a solution. I had to change the call to my function:

```
document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = chartTurn.generateLegend().replace(/\"0-legend"/g, 'legend');
$("#js-legend > ul > li").on("click", function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;

  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  while (target.nodeName !== 'LI') {
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
  var parent = target.parentElement;
  var chart = Chart.instances[0];
  var index = Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children).indexOf(target);
  console.log(chart.legend.legendItems[index]);

  Pie_onClickLegend_HighlightOnSlice(event.originalEvent, chart.legend.legendItems[index],chart);
})
```

And since I used "this.chart" in "Pie_onClickLegend_HighlightOnSlice", now I have to pass also the chartInstance I want to use:

```
function Pie_onClickLegend_HighlightOnSlice(event, legendItem, chartInstance) {
   if (chartInstance === undefined){
       chartInstance = this.chart;
   }

   [...]
}
```